# Consequence of unused tourist visa for UK

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, tourist-visas

Last year, I was lucky to get a 6 months, multiple visa to UK but my girlfriend could not get the visa so I cancelled my trip and my visa got expired. I know in some countries like Spain if you don't use the visa, it is called "visa shopping" and it has consequence. I would like to know if there such a thing for UK as well?

Comment: That's not what visa shopping is. Visa shopping is when you apply at a particular Schengen consulate for a visa but use that visa to travel to another country.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely nothing happens should you not make use of the UK visa issued to you. It's irrelevant that it was not used; if anything, it's a positive in your favor in terms of performance. Visa shopping refers to those who are refused a visa by one Schengen country who apply to another member state. While the UK is part of the EU, currently, it is not a Schengen state.